# why function aeron_driver_context_bindings_clientd_create_entries is invoked twice during the aeronmd init process?

Tags: c, aeron

During the aeronmd's main process of aeron-driver in c code, function `aeron_driver_context_bindings_clientd_create_entries` is invoked twice, one in `aeron_driver_context_init` and another in `aeron_driver_init`.
Is that a duplication? or there are some reasons for the design consideration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method does two things, it allocates space for bindings and it allocates space for interceptors.  There are some bindings that need the space earlier in the initialisation phase, so we pre-create some space up front.  However, it is still possible to add interceptors after the context has initialised, therefore we need to double check that there is space in the list available for those as well.

There is probably a refactoring to separate out the state information of transport bindings vs interceptors and initialise them separately.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But in the code of ```aeron_driver_context_bindings_clientd_create_entries``` I didn't find the allocate action for interceptors but only the ```aeron_driver_context_bindings_clientd_entry_t``` allocated based on the interceptor_bindings number.
And I also didn't find the interceptors adding place between  ```aeron_driver_context_init ``` and ```aeron_driver_init``` in the main process of aeronmd, could you kindly give more information about the interceptor adding time.

Comment: These lines allocate space for the interceptors: https://github.com/real-logic/aeron/blob/325fd15e8d0044432548194ec8a2c3016a15717f/aeron-driver/src/main/c/aeron_driver_context.c#L1187:L1199.  These lines allocate space for the binding: https://github.com/real-logic/aeron/blob/325fd15e8d0044432548194ec8a2c3016a15717f/aeron-driver/src/main/c/aeron_driver_context.c#L1201:L1232.  You won't see it in the open source version as the UDP bindings can lazily initialise.  However some bindings need more upfront initialisation, i.e. before the interceptors may have been specified.  DPDK as an example.

Comment: Does the interceptor allocation just increase the num_entries? or there are some work involved in the commercial version? I also wonder what competence does the commercial have.

Comment: `aeron_driver_context_bindings_clientd_create_entries` walks the incoming and outgoing interceptor chains and calculates `num_entries` then ensures there is enough space available for them.

Comment: The commercial extensions include accelerators for ef_vi (xilinx cards), DPDK (AWS), and VMA (Mellanox cards) as well as support for driver to driver encryption using OpenSSL.